# Can we reduce the scientific terms?

Tags: discussion, scope, content-level

Well I think Its my personal problem .When ask a question its answers are in scientific terms and I was unable to understand it . Can you reduce the scientific terms,? and I know it is little bit difficult because your well versed in science but I am not  ,so please give me answers that I can understand

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the welcome message, this site is

> a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics.

This means that the bulk of the discussion on this site will require scientific terminology to occur; we're not going to "reduce the scientific terms" we use on this site because there might be someone out there that doesn't understand them. Sorry if this sounds harsh, but that's just the way it is.

If it is on a question that *you yourself* ask, then it is your responsibility to phrase your question in a way that makes it clear what you do and don't understand, what level you're at, and the sorts of terminology and tools that you have not yet studied, so that answerers can know what level of detail and jargon to include in their answers. This should be done in the question itself, but if you get an answer that you don't understand it is perfectly OK to comment under that answer specifying which parts you find beyond your current scope.

It's hard to say anything more specific, though, because you currently have [a single non-deleted question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386526/what-caused-the-big-bang) and it has no answers, so if you're referring to deleted questions of yours then nobody (except ♦ moderators) can see them so we can't help there. If you're referring to questions by other people, then as mentioned above we're not going to change the answers to suit you.

However, if you do find an answer (to someone else's question) that you find interesting but which you don't fully understand, then it is perfectly OK to post a new question asking for clarification and explaining in detail which parts of the answer you find confusing (and, again, being very specific about what level you want answers to be pitched at).

Comment: But people should try to make an effort to write out abbreviations.  Also in titles. Is EPR about Einstein-Podolski-Rosen or about Electron Paramagnetic Resonance?

Comment: @Pieter Sure, but that seems to be a different issue from what Akash is asking about here.